# Dependent dropdown with vue js (without ajax)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a dependent dropdown using vue js. I have created 2 dropdowns:

```
    <div id="app">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="100">One</label>
        <select v-model="val1" name="" id="100">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
        </select>
        <div id="hide" v-if="show">
            <label for="200">Two</label>
            <select name="" id="2">
                <option value="11">ten</option>
                <option value="12">eleven</option>
                <option value="13">twelve</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my vue script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        value: 2,
        val1:'',
        show:false
    }
computed: {
    showNext: function() {
      if (this.value == this.val1) {
        show:true
      }
    }
}
});
</script>
```

As per my requirement, first dropdown should be visible and second dropdown should not been shown. It should be shown if option with value 2 is selected from the first dropdown and should remain hidden if other value is other option is selected that doesn't satisfy the if statement.

But in my case both dropdown is visible at start of the page. What might be the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missunderstood `computed`. Also, I would advise to use `===` , not `==`

Your `computed` should be `show` :

```
computed: {
    show (): {
      if (this.value === this.val1) {
        return true;
      }
     else
        return false;
    }
}
```

Try to create quick JSFiddle if the issue is still there and I will help you to fix it.

Comment: Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rzzdkc1s/) can you refactor it.

Comment: all working now :) You should not use `v-if={{ show }}` . Correct usage is: `v-if='show'`